# exception: "unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts"

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a **Mysql** database in an online server. I try to connect with it through a **Xamarin Android application** (C#) in **Visual Studio 2015**.This is my connection string:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Port=3306;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Everything was working just fine, i could connect with the database without any problem through the app but suddenly i got this exception. I have access to my database through web but not through my application. My router firewall is disabled, my windows firewall is disabled (i also added an exception for port 3306). i tried the same process with my PC with another web provider and i still get the same error (so my rooter is not the problem i guess).I also tried the same code in another PC with another web provider and everything worked just fine!

Any solution please? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the server permission of your mysql login usersname at first.
As you said, you can access the database via web with the same username, so I think that your mysql login user only allow the LOCALHOST script to connect the server.